# I have this python code that I am trying to turn into javascript but I cant seem to figure out which if statement. to use

Tags: javascript, python

This is the python code im trying to convert into javascript.

```
ime = input("Enter your name: \n\n")

# correction made by AmyHubbertx
for c in ime:

    c = c.upper()
    if (c == "A"):
        print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..######..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n\n")
    elif (c == "B"):
        print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..#####...\n..#....#..\n..######..\n\n")
    elif (c == "C"):
        print("..######..\n..#.......\n..#.......\n..#.......\n..######..\n\n")
    elif (c == "D"):
        print("..#####...\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#####...\n\n")
```

I want to be able to write anything and get each letter written to the page. This current code writes 'a' even if you put the wrong letter.

How can I input something and have it write to the page?

```
/*function yourName()*/
    let name = prompt("Enter Your Name")

    if (i === 'a' || 'A'){
        document.write(("..######..<br>..#........#..<br>..######..<br>..#........#..<br>..#........#..<br><br>"))
    } if ( i = 'b' || 'B'){
        document.write(("..######..<br>..#........#..<br>..#####...<br>..#........#..<br>..######..<br><br>"))
    } if ( i = 'c' || 'C'){
        document.write(("..######..<br>..#.......<br>..#.......<br>..#.......<br>..######..<br><br>"))
    }
/*}*/
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase

Comment: You've written `if` instead of `else if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many issues. `=` is assignment and `==` or `===` is comparison just like in Python.

Also not you should NEVER use `document.write` after the page has loaded. It will wipe the page.

Here is a working version taking all letters you type (as long as they are A, B, or C)

```js
const name = prompt("Enter Your Name", "CAB").trim().toUpperCase()
let text = "No name given";

const chars = {
  'A': "..######..<br>..#....#..<br>..######..<br>..#....#..<br>..#....#..<br>",
  'B': "..######..<br>..#....#..<br>..#####...<br>..#....#..<br>..######..<br>",
  'C': "..######..<br>..#.......<br>..#.......<br>..#.......<br>..######..<br>",
}

if (name.length > 0) {
  text = name.split("").map(c => chars[c] || "X<br/>"); // return the character or X if not found
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = `<pre>${text.join("</pre><pre>")}</pre>`;
}
```

```css
pre {display: inline-block; float: left }
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you mplungjan. But how would i be able to out put more that 1 letter. At the moment the code you put there only lets me do one letter at a time. How could I document.write the entire name...

Comment: Also you mention to NEVER use document.write what would you suggest I use instead?

Comment: @therealslim I made you a working version so you can write a name (as long as it is only using A, B, and C)

Comment: Yes but if i write AB it dosent work. It outputs no name given

Comment: It does for me. If I type AB I get A (newline) B

Comment: YES!!!!! awesome thank you! you're the man! appreciate the help.

Comment: I changed the HTML a bit. Now the letters are next to eachother

Comment: Even better! maybe you can also help me with this if you have time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73190748/i-would-like-to-add-a-new-pokemon-image-for-the-main-character-to-jump-over-afte

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` condition is wrong.

`if (i === 'a' || i === 'A') {` is what you need, otherwise the statement reads:

> if `i` is equal to 'a' OR 'A'
> Instead of
> if `i` is equal to 'a' OR `i` is equal to 'A'

Because you aren't comparing the second part to anything it will return true.

Comment: Aweosme thank you!! that makes alot of sense. But how could I iterate thorough the entire name? so it can print the entire name to the page?