# I want to add Math.floor(Math.random()) to the images

Tags: javascript, math

How could I make this line of code work properly so it gives me a random image instead of it being in order? I tried it this was but that was a no go. How could I use Math.floor-math random properly here?

```
  **block.style.content = `Math.floor((Math.random() * url(${nextImage()}))`;**
```

```
var character = document.getElementById("character");
var block = document.getElementById("block");
var counter = 0;
var index = 0;

const images = [
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/001.png',
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/002.png',
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/003.png',
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/004.png',
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/005.png',
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/006.png',
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/007.png',
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/008.png',
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/009.png'

  ];
  
  function nextImage() {
    index++;
    if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
    return images[index];
  }

  function jump() {
    if (character.classList.contains("animate")) {
      return
    }
    character.classList.add("animate");
    setTimeout(function() {
      character.classList.remove("animate");
      block.style.content = `Math.floor((Math.random() * url(${nextImage()}))`;      
    }, 300);
  }
```

Comment: why not generate a random index inside `nextImage`? Also this feels like https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: `const nextImage = () => images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length]; .... block.style.content = \`url(${nextImage()})\``

Comment: You are the Man!!!!! So helpful. @mplungjan!!! do you have a YouTube channel I could follow.

Comment: Not really. Thanks for asking. PS: You can remove your answer and delete the question. It is VERY specific to you and perhaps less so for people coming after

Answer (score 0):

```
const images = [
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/001.png',
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/002.png',
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/003.png',
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/004.png',
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/005.png',
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/006.png',
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/007.png',
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/008.png',
    'https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/pokemon/009.png'

  ];

**const nextImage = () => images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];** 


  function nextFlyingImage() {
    if (index >= flyingImages.length) index = 0;
    return flyingImages[index];
  }

  function jump() {
    if (character.classList.contains("animate")) {
      return image[index]
    }

    character.classList.add("animate");
    setTimeout(function() {
      character.classList.remove("animate");
      block.style.content = `url(${nextImage()})`;
    //   flyingPokemon.style.content = `url(${nextFlyingImage()})`      
    }, 300);
  }
```