# The keys won't remove transition after clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, deprecated, keycode

I think the problem could be with the
**const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);**

It seems that the keyCode is deprecated. Ive searched online and it says to use .key but when I did that and changed everything else with the class of key to key it also didn't work. Can someone aid me here?

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`); // will highlight the key pressed
  if (!audio) return; // if there is no audio the stop the function from running.
  audio.currentTime = 0; // will rewind each sound to the start so they can be played without delays
  audio.play();
  key.classList.add('playing');
});

function removeTransition(e) {
  if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return; // skip if its not a transform
  this.classList.remove('playing')
}

const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitioned', removeTransition));
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  background: url('./millenium-mps1000-frontpage-banner.png') bottom center;
  background-size: cover;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.keys {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.key {
  border: .4rem solid black;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  transition: all .07s;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5rem black;
}

.playing {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-color: #ffc600;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem pink;
}

kbd {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.sound {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  color: #ffc600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <script src="index.js"></script> -->

  <div class="keys">
    <div data-key="65" class="key">
      <kbd>A</kbd>
      <span class="sound">clap</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="83" class="key">
      <kbd>S</kbd>
      <span class="sound">hihat</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="68" class="key">
      <kbd>D</kbd>
      <span class="sound">kick</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="70" class="key">
      <kbd>F</kbd>
      <span class="sound">openhat</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="71" class="key">
      <kbd>G</kbd>
      <span class="sound">boom</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="72" class="key">
      <kbd>H</kbd>
      <span class="sound">ride</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="74" class="key">
      <kbd>F</kbd>
      <span class="sound">snare</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="75" class="key">
      <kbd>F</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tom</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="76" class="key">
      <kbd>F</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tink</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="70" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="71" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="72" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="74" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="75" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="76" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I got will do for next time. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not related to `keycode` because it does highlight the `div`. It's because of typo event name is `transitionend`. However I wanted to say that if you long press a key then it gets stuck with the `active` class because event will not fire if no transition happened.

Edit: to remedy this, remove the `playing` class before adding it back on (for a bit of a millisecond).

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  if (!audio) return;
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  audio.play();


  key.classList.remove('playing');
  setTimeout(function() {
    key.classList.add('playing');
  })
  

});

function removeTransition(e) {
  if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
  this.classList.remove('playing')
}

const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
```

```css
html {
  font - size: 10 px;
  background: url('./millenium-mps1000-frontpage-banner.png') bottom center;
  background - size: cover;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.keys {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.key {
  border: .4rem solid black;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  transition: all .07s;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5rem black;
}

.playing {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-color: #ffc600;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem pink;
}

kbd {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.sound {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  color: #ffc600;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- <script src="index.js"></script> -->

  <div class="keys">
    <div data-key="65" class="key">
      <kbd>A</kbd>
      <span class="sound">clap</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="83" class="key">
      <kbd>S</kbd>
      <span class="sound">hihat</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="68" class="key">
      <kbd>D</kbd>
      <span class="sound">kick</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="70" class="key">
      <kbd>F</kbd>
      <span class="sound">openhat</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="71" class="key">
      <kbd>G</kbd>
      <span class="sound">boom</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="72" class="key">
      <kbd>H</kbd>
      <span class="sound">ride</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="74" class="key">
      <kbd>F</kbd>
      <span class="sound">snare</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="75" class="key">
      <kbd>F</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tom</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="76" class="key">
      <kbd>F</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tink</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="70" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="71" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="72" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="74" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="75" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="76" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>
</body>
```

Comment: even if I press it fast it still stays highlighted :(

Comment: I fixed that in the snippet

Comment: I run your code here and it runs fine! but when I add the new code to mine it does nothing? any ideas?

Comment: I looked through the css and html and it Dosent seem like you added anything else to the code besides ` key.classList.remove('playing');
    setTimeout(function() {
      key.classList.add('playing');
    })`

Comment: Yes it's your code mostly